# PHPunit ignoring Laravel's .env database config

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I am building an API with Laravel 5.4 and writing integration tests using PHPunit, all within a Vagrant vm. The tests are working fine and is connecting to the database via credentials defined in `.env.testing` which is being called via line `$app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');` in `tests/TestCase.php`.

This is all fine, but when I try to run this on the staging server, PHPunit is not calling the environment file and therefore cannot run the tests. I have found that the tests work when populating the variables into phpunit.xml, however I don't like this approach because the values are hardcoded into this file.

Can anyone help me determine what may be different between these two environments for them to behave differently?

Comment: Correct me if I was wrong. I can run with env variable in command like `php artisan migrate --env="testing"`. This is just for migration. My testing env file is `.env.testing`